# Selecting an anchor tag within nested li elements

Tags: jquery

I am having the following HTML

```
<ul class="nav sidebar-menu">
 <li>.....</li>
  <ul>
   <li>.....</li>
   <li>
      <ul clas="sub-menu">
        <li><a></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
```

With the above HTML some classes are being added internally and I am getting shadow for the anchor elements. 
And now within Inspect Element I could find the following

```
.page-sidebar .sidebar-menu>li>.submenu>li.active:last-child a {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 4px -2px }
.page-sidebar .sidebar-menu>li>.submenu>li.active:first-child a {
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 4px 4px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.15);}
```

If I disable the above within inspect element I am able to remove the shadow for the elements. How can I select the above using JQuery. Any links, suggestions will also help. Thanks

Comment: jquery uses selectors, so it would be: `$("_YOUR_SELECTOR_HERE")`

Comment: why can't you remove or comment it out in the stylesheet?

Comment: `clas="sub-menu"` has a typo, and the class `.submenu` isn't going to select `sub-menu`

Comment: @charlietfl that will affect the elemets in other places. Thanks

Comment: In that case write more specific rule for this instance that wouldn't affect other locations such as adding an id before each selector or combination of classes

Answer (score 0):

Use a JQuery class or Id selector, in this case you could use:

```
$(".sub-menu")
```

However, if there is more than one element with the sub-menu class it will select them all.  You could also add an id to the element like this:

```
<ul class="nav sidebar-menu">
 <li>.....</li>
  <ul>
   <li>.....</li>
   <li>
      <ul id="elementid" class="sub-menu">
        <li><a></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
```

Then select it with the Id selector

```
$("#elementid")
```

Comment: w3schools has a good reference on jquery selectors:  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp